# Synchronized Queue?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, queue, blockingqueue

I have two threads for an online game im making. One thread receives two X and Y number, and the other thread sends out the X and Y numbers to everyone logged into the server. Basically I need a queue, that will allow the first thread to add a 2D array to the Queue, and to keep doing this, while at the same time, pulling the arrays off and deleted the array from the queue to use to send to the other players. Is there a way to do this? I know I need a synchronized queue, but how do I synchronized one, is that called a blocking Queue?

Overall I need a queue that is synchronized, that will allow two threads to throw stuff in and to take stuff out. Is it possible?

-Dan

Comment: You tagged blockingqueue, it does not meet your needs?

Comment: Any BlockingQueue will fit the spec.

Answer (score -1):

A blocking queue is a queue in which:

1. adding elements to it, blocks the caller thread in case there isn't available space on the queue, until an element is removed (by some other thread);
2. removing elements from it, blocks the caller thread in case there aren't any elements to remove, until an element it added (by some other thread).

In order to achieve the functionality of a *thread-safe* (though not necessarily synchronized) queue, you'd typically use one of `BlockingQueue`'s implementations, such as `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: You add more confusion than clarity ( by bringing in Thread-safety Vs sync'n point) - This is definitely a candidate for BlockingQueue. Sync'd wrappers should be used only if client side sync is wanted.  Your second example is again a BQ - so why not recommend a BQ to start with ..

Comment: @Bhaskar I agree BQ is the recommended option in this case and I'll edit the answer accordingly. However, as the question referred *synchronized* queue, it's important to clarify that *thread-safety* is actually required and that `LinkedBlockingQueue` isn't synchronized.

Comment: Wait why cant a blocking queue be used for a thread safe queue? Could a "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>" work?

Comment: @DanielH, ConcurrentLinkedQueue => will not block on empty/full conditions , but allows more throughput/concurrent operations than any BlockingQueues. Depends upon your requirements. Both CLQ and BQ are thread-safe.

Comment: @DanielH a BQ *can* be used as a thread safe queue. Actually it has to be thread safe.

Comment: Last questions, When I implement the LinkedBlockingQueue should I give it the interface of Queue? Because if I do (ex: Queue<int[][]> xy = new LinkedBlockingQueue<int[][]>();) then for some reason I cant call the put and take methods. Only when I use the interface BlockingQueue can I use those methods. Do you know what is going on? The take a put methods are within the LinkedBlockingQueue class, whats going on here?

Comment: These methods are declared in BlockingQueue interface - not in Queue. Yes you should use BlockingQueue interface to refer to a LinkedBlockingQueue impl.

Comment: @DanielH `put` and `take` are methods added in `BlockingQueue` and don't exist in `Queue`. These are exactly the methods that block. A generic `Queue` isn't necesarily blocking (like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) and therefore you can't access these methods via the more generic `Queue` interface.